# How do i get to a CMD Prompt screen on my ThinkPad which runs Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

How do i get to enter any commands / get to a command prompt screen?  I want to download Java. All i know how to do is click on the icons on / from the Desktop screen once the Lenovo ThinkPad comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an icon of a black screen, should say Terminal when you hover above it. That gives you a command prompt. You can also switch to a full screen virtual terminal using ctrl-alt-Fx (x being 1 to 6). To get back to the graphical environment after that use ctrl-alt-F7 or F8.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for the "terminal" is Ctrl+Alt+T. To open another tab in an already open terminal window, use Ctrl+Shift+T.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to start `Ubuntu`'s terminal is:
Press the **Windows** button on your keyboard, and type in `terminal`, and then it should pop up as an option, so you can click it with the mouse or press Enter.

But actually in this case, if you *just* want to install `Java` I would instead recommend typing in `software center` at that prompt, which should make **Ubuntu Software Center** appear, and then you can use that to search for and install `Java`.